# HAProxy Active Passive VIP Issue

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have a very basic question, we all know that when we configure
HAProxy in the Active-Passive manner then there is a VIP. Outside
service will access the VIP and the traffic will be routed to
appropriate inner services.  Now, my question is if the LAN
connectivity between the Active-Passive HAProxy goes down will the VIP
still be able to perform the same task? Or the behavior will be different?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what software you use for VIP management. But the most likely scenario is that both instances will try to allocate the VIP and that might cause a major outage. This is known as a split-brain situation, read up on it in the internet.